# Prometheus metrics not showing up using prometheus go client

Tags: go, metrics, prometheus

I am using prometheus golang client. The code snippet is below. The build for the same is working okay.

The issue is that only go metrics are shown. xyz_* metrics are missing. I call the initMetrics() as first thing in the main() func.

```
// Declaring prometheus metric counters
var (

  metric_prefix = "xyz_"

  xyzAPICallsCounter = prometheus.NewCounterVec(
    prometheus.CounterOpts{
      Name: metric_prefix + "api_calls_total" ,
      Help: "Number of calls to xyz endpoint",
    },
    []string{
      // Type of api call. Present values 
      "type",
      // Method can be "add", "delete", "getall", "get", "create", "ensure"
      "method",
      // Status is success or failed
      "status",
    },
  )

)

    func initMetrics(){
    prometheus.MustRegister(xyzAPICallsCounter)
    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    }
```

Edit: I changed the initMetrics() function to below and now there are no metrics at all and the below error message.

```
func initMetrics(){
  var registry = prometheus.NewRegistry()
  registry.MustRegister(
    xyzAPICallsCounter,
  )
  http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.HandlerFor(registry, promhttp.HandlerOpts{}))
  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: The error message means what it says, something else is already using port 8080 so it can't start a new web server listening on that port.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, you can ignore the error part. I am certain it was a mistake on my part. I ran kubectl exec -it <podname> -- /<go-binary> after I deployed the service. It was bound to give the message.

Comment: So now there are no metrics and no error message?

Comment: Otherwise, the :8080/metrics endpoint stills gives me an empty response.

Comment: Yes. no error message and an empty response.

Comment: was this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

CounterVec is a collection of counters and is not exported until it has counters in it.

See the [code docs](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/prometheus/counter.go#L99) and [example](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang/blob/master/examples/random/main.go) for more info.

Comment: I have counter increments throughout my code. Will these work?

xyzAPICallsCounter.WithLabelValues("pool","exists", "failed").Inc()

Comment: Do they show up on the metrics endpoint after calling `Inc()`?

Comment: No they don't. Only go metrics in the first case. If I define my own registry,  then it is blank.

Comment: Can you show more code where you're calling `Inc()`? Could you also update your snippet to reflect how you're creating/registering everything?
The go metrics will definitely not show up since you're creating your own registry instead of using the default one.